# Best model or method for my time series data and question?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, dataset, model

I have 2 sets of data
Set 1 is composed of time, t and number of u units , (sales data)
Set 2 is composed of time, t, and number of s sessions, ( count# of event s occured)

Things I would like to know:
Given sales data (Set 1), can i predict how many events will happen ? (Can I predict the next element in Set 2 given Set 1 ?)

what is the "time lag" between a change in sales and events? (How does a change in an element of Set 1 change a series of elements in Set 2?)

What is the best model or method to answer these questions? Do i need to consider probability, or is there a method to estimate a function that behaves like my data?

Aside from my initial question, i am also interested in knowing why the suggested method is the best method.

I know i've asked for so much, but thank you so much in advanced. This is a personal project I am doing to learn new skills to implement in real world problems soon hopefully :)